# mysql CURRENT_TIMESTAMP give me all 0

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, utc

If I run the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `price_s` ADD COLUMN `ts` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  AFTER `price_s_id` ;
```

The new column would be populated with `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.
Value in this column won't get updated to Current Timestamp until I modify the column, i.e. `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` seems to work fine.

If I run :

```
SELECT version( ) , @@time_zone , @@system_time_zone , NOW( ) , UTC_TIMESTAMP( )
```

I got:

```
'5.5.15', '+10:00', 'EST', '2012-08-23 14:56:59', '2012-08-23 04:56:59'
```

I'd like to store the UTC time in the column `ts`, how do I do that?

Not sure if this is relevant, I have tried to generate the `mysql.time_zone*` tables:

```
Miranda-Macbook: ./mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | ./mysql -p -u root mysql
Enter password: Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/+VERSION' as time zone. Skipping it.

Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh87' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh88' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh89' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Mideast/Riyadh87' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Mideast/Riyadh88' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Mideast/Riyadh89' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
```

Thanks @Sameer and @Marc B.
Now I understands timestamp more.(with the help of this [article](http://developerinsight.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp/))
It is already stored in UTC, so what I need is actually:

```
SET time_zone = 'SYSTEM';
UPDATE tablename SET ts=now()
```

Comment: I hope you are not expecting that the existing rows in the table will get the current timestamp when you add that column. The existing rows will get the value of 0. Any new rows inserted would have the current timestamp. For existing rows, you will need to run a one-time update command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (ts) VALUES (now())
UPDATE yourtable SET ts=now()
```

As long as whatever you're stuffing into the ts field is a valid mysql timestamp string (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) it doesn't matter WHAT the timezone is. That only becomes relevant upon conversion or retrieval - mysql datefields themselves have no concept of timezones, they're just repositories of some date/time data.